# PostgreSQL, How to re-cast a table column from Integer to Decimal?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'd like to alter a PostgreSQL column to convert from `integer` to `decimal`, setting all `integer` values to `<value>.0`.  How do I do this?

Comment: `DECIMAL` is really `NUMERIC` in Pg, for what it's worth.

If you need to do any explicit transformations, see the `USING` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table_name ALTER some_column TYPE decimal;
```

Relevant [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/sql-altertable.html).